# How to solve a symbolic system of equations in Matlab

Tags: matlab, symbolic-math, equation-solving

I know it has to be a stupid error,but I really can't solve a system of this type:

```
b =

 a2*cos(q1 + q2) + a1*cos(q1)
 a2*sin(q1 + q2) + a1*sin(q1)
                 d1 + d4 + q3

>> solve(b,[q1,q2,q3,q4])
Warning: The solutions are parametrized by the symbols:
z1 = C_

> In solve at 190 

ans = 

    a1: [1x1 sym]
    d1: [1x1 sym]
    d4: [1x1 sym]
    q1: [1x1 sym]
    q2: [1x1 sym]
    q3: [1x1 sym]
    q4: [1x1 sym]
```

basically I want my program to see a1,d1,d4 as parameters and q1,q2,q3,q4 as variables.
that's why I call solve(b,[q1,q2,q3,q4]) in this form,but it tries to solve even in the symbolic values that I haven't put into the vector.

Ty in advice for your help.

Comment: just noticed that of course,b is not a system of equation,it miss the '=out' part,but how can I attach it then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to tips of [`solve`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/solve.html):

> > ... the call [b,a] = solve(eqns,b,a) assigns the solutions for a assigned to a and the solutions for b assigned to b.

However you probably want to solve, `b - [e1 e2 e3]' = 0` for only 3 variables (Let's say `q1 q2 q3`), you can't solve it for 4 variables, that would be 3 equations and 4 variables which does't make sense.

Since I think that it is related to some mechanical system you may want to solve for only real values. You can either do this `solve (eqn, 'Real', true)` or declare real values: `syms a1 a2 ... real`.

However you still wouldn't get a pretty result, unless you use the `'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints'` option in this case:

```
syms q1 q2 q3 d1 d4 a1 a2 e1 e2 e3 real

b = [...
    a2*cos(q1 + q2) + a1*cos(q1)
    a2*sin(q1 + q2) + a1*sin(q1)
    d1 + d4 + q3];

res = solve(b-[e1 e2 e3]', q1, q2, q3, 'IgnoreAnalyticConstraints', true);
```

Output: (simplified)

```
>> simplify(res.q1)

ans =

 2*atan((2*a1*e2 + (- a1^4 + 2*a1^2*a2^2 + 2*a1^2*e1^2 + 2*a1^2*e2^2 - a2^4 + 2*a2^2*e1^2 + 2*a2^2*e2^2 - e1^4 - 2*e1^2*e2^2 - e2^4)^(1/2))/(a1^2 + 2*a1*e1 - a2^2 + e1^2 + e2^2))
 2*atan((2*a1*e2 - (- a1^4 + 2*a1^2*a2^2 + 2*a1^2*e1^2 + 2*a1^2*e2^2 - a2^4 + 2*a2^2*e1^2 + 2*a2^2*e2^2 - e1^4 - 2*e1^2*e2^2 - e2^4)^(1/2))/(a1^2 + 2*a1*e1 - a2^2 + e1^2 + e2^2))

>> res.q2

ans =

 -2*atan(((- a1^2 + 2*a1*a2 - a2^2 + e1^2 + e2^2)*(a1^2 + 2*a1*a2 + a2^2 - e1^2 - e2^2))^(1/2)/(- a1^2 + 2*a1*a2 - a2^2 + e1^2 + e2^2))
  2*atan(((- a1^2 + 2*a1*a2 - a2^2 + e1^2 + e2^2)*(a1^2 + 2*a1*a2 + a2^2 - e1^2 - e2^2))^(1/2)/(- a1^2 + 2*a1*a2 - a2^2 + e1^2 + e2^2))

>> res.q3

ans =

 e3 - d4 - d1
 e3 - d4 - d1
```

Comment: that's exactly it! q4 is in the code I posted by mistake,it was an extra degree of freedom of another robot. will try and report in a minute! thanks a lot

Comment: when I do simplify(res.q1) I get an horrinble form in exponential and not your form in atan,do I have to use some other methods?

Comment: Well I believe exponential and trigonometric form are convertible to each other. Is `res.q1` before simplification in exponential form too?

Comment: it fixed by himself restarting matlab,I had sever very good answers,but yours is the best :) thank you a lot

Answer (score 1):

As written, you're currently trying to solve two sets of equations. The first is the three `b` equations equal to zero. The second is the vector `[q1,q2,q3,q4]` equal to zero. Because your first equation is not a function of a vector but rather of only the components of this vector, `solve` sees the second argument as an equation rather than variable to solve for. To solve for the desired variables, simply list them as per the documentation:

```
s = solve(b,q1,q2,q3,q4)
```

or

```
[q1,q2,q3,q4] = solve(b,q1,q2,q3,q4)
```

Now you will obtain non-zero solutions. However, you'll still get a warning as you obviously have three equations and are trying to solve for four unknowns and there are possibly an infinite number of solutions over the real numbers. In fact `q4` isn't used in these equations at all.

Comment: oh,that seems better.

Comment: If I do [code]( b=[a2*cos(q1+a2)+a1*cos(q1)==x;a2*sin(q1+q2)+a1*sin(q1)==y;+d1+d4+q3==z]); [q1,q2,q3]=solve(b,q1,q2,q3)) i get this http://pastebin.com/31SSui4E I guess is beacouse my solutions don't always exist,do I have a chance in reversing that system then? even if it needs to take as hp some conditions,like sin(q1)!=0 Ty for your answer,it was exactly my (first) problem

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax is:

```
 b=[a2*cos(q1 + q2) + a1*cos(q1)==0;
    a2*sin(q1 + q2) + a1*sin(q1)==0;
    d1 + d4 + q3==0]
```

Comment: ok,thx...but I still can't do it :/ take this example 'code'( b =
 
 l2*cos(a1 + a2) + l1*cos(a1) == x
 l2*sin(a1 + a2) + l2*sin(a1) == y
 
>> [a,c]=solve(b,a1,a2))

Comment: in the case I added in the comment (didn't figure that pressing enter will post the answer) I get http://pastebin.com/c1Lf8i1b after calling  [a,c]=solve(b,a1,a2)

Comment: The `==0` is implied if omitted, though it's usually good practice to include it as it help with readability.